# Material UI: Nested component style override not applying

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to CSS in JS and I'm a bit stuck on component styles in Material UI - specifically how to override a nested element style.  I've been following t[he official docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/) but it's not helping.

In the styles object I have set:

```
listItemText: {
  fontSize: 0.8,
  color: '#ccc'
},
span: {
  fontSize: 0.8,
  color: '#ccc'
}
```

The component looks like:

```
<ListItemText
  primary={text}
  classes={{
    root: classes.listItemText,
    span: classes.span
  }}
/>
```

As you can see in the demo linked below, the font size and colour is getting applied to the parent component, but not the nested span. How can I apply it on the span?

[image: Edit Material demo]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. Each component has it's own CSS API...

It would be better if this was documented more clearly.

```
<ListItemText
  primary={obj.label}
  classes={{
    root: classes.listItemText,
    primary: classes.listItemText
  }}
/>
```

https://material-ui.com/api/list-item-text/

Comment: Hi, I am stuck with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56151942/materialui-how-to-overwrite-styles-of-nested-mui-component , perhaps you can help me understand, big thanks!